# echo overwites beginning of line in a bash script

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to formulate curl requests (echo just for a check) based on variables I got from another curl query

My first curl query result assigned to $invno_list variable is

```
,result,table,invno,latitude,longitude
,_result,0,16734,44.6707726,15.2820759
,_result,0,16768,44.7376213,15.2164268
,_result,0,18061,44.6654625,14.6602612
```

my script is here

```
declare -i line_number=0
for inv_line in $(echo "$invno_list" | awk -F'\\\\r\\\\n' '{print}');do
    line_size=${#inv_line} 
    if [ ! $line_number -eq 0 ] && [ $line_size -gt 1 ] #avoiding header line and empty line (last)
    then
    invno=$(echo "$inv_line" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $4}')
    lat=$(echo "$inv_line" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $5}')
    lon=$(echo "$inv_line" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $6}')
    echo "invno is ${invno} lat is ${lat} and lon is ${lon}" #checking variables
    echo "curl -X GET -k -i \"${ownURL}?lat=$lat&lon=${lon}&units=metric\""
fi    
    line_number=$line_number+1
done
```

The result of this run is

```
invno is 16734 lat is 44.6707726 and lon is 15.2820759
&units=metric" -i "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=44.6707726&lon=15.2820759
invno is 16768 lat is 44.7376213 and lon is 15.2164268
&units=metric" -i "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=44.7376213&lon=15.2164268
invno is 18061 lat is 44.6654625 and lon is 14.6602612
&units=metric" -i "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=44.6654625&lon=14.6602612
```

I would expect results to be following type

```
invno is 40336 lat is 44.6777115 and lon is 15.2872734
curl -X GET -k -i "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=44.6777115&lon=15.2872734&units=metric"
```

Can someone please suggest me what is wrong

Comment: Looks like `$inv_line` ends with a carriage return.

Comment: Yes I'm not sure what the problem is - works fine for me. I'm not sure how his expected output is to be reached from this dataset - or how the expected output is 'incorrect' specifically

Answer (score 0):

Look like Shawn was right there were \r sign who messed up everything

This line fixed that

```
$(echo "$invno_list" | awk '{sub(/\r/,"",$NF); print}
```